# Repairable CPU fan for socket 115x

Tags: fan-controller

Background: My socket 1155 CPU fan (Intel brand) struggles to move, very likely because of dust buildup (there was quite a bit of dust in the case when I opened it).

Now I *know* that computer fans can be repaired, and I've done that myself for a power supply fan. However, I'm struggling with opening up the Intel CPU fan: Removing the sticker doesn't reveal the usual pad over the axis which you can open. Looking inside the slit (which is quite large, making it easy for dust to get in) shows the part with the coils is attached by contacts which move a bit, but I can't separate the assembly.

Therefore I'm looking a socket 115x CPU fan with the following characteristics:

- As silent as possible
- Normal cooling requirements, the CPU is not overclocked etc.
- At least somewhat resistant to dust getting in (no big openings like in the Intel fan)
- Repairable: Should be constructed in a way that makes it possible to open it up, lubricate the axis, and clean dust if necessary.

The last point is the most important one, and I hope to find someone here who has done this himself, and can share the brand and model for which it worked.

(Yes, I know I can just pay the 15 EUR everytime it breaks down and get a new one, and that this is less effort than repairing, yada yada, but it's a matter of principle: Why throw away a perfectly good component that just needs a bit of cleaning or lubricating? There's enough electronic garbage, I don't need unnecessarily add to it.)

(I couldn't find tags like "fan" or "repairable", "fan-controller" seems to be the best that I can find. Please edit with better tags as appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention your location, but here are some options that ship free to UK (I used the zip code of Buckingham palace). You might also notice that I am only giving you Amazon links. This is because that is the only EU friendly purveyor I am familiar with as North American based companies will get hit with tax importation and VAT.

### [Recommended Option: Cooler Master MasterLiquid Lite £38 (MSRP: £45)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Cooler-Master-MasterLiquid-MasterFan-MLW-D12M-A20PW-R1/dp/B06WRRDS73/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1532613432&sr=1-1&keywords=cooler+masterliquid+lite+120)

[image: Cooler Master MasterLiquid Lite]
So I know you asked specifically for a fan upgrade, but I wanted to recommend a cheap water cooling system as they are quieter than your traditional CPU fan and also more efficient at removing heat from your processor than your average fan. **This water cooler is rated at 8 dBA which according to the decibel scale chart is quieter than a ticking watch**. Also according to your extra requirement, you

> hope to find someone here who has done this himself, and can share the brand and model for which it worked.

This just so happened to be the exact cooler I helped to install on a friend's LGA 1155 processor. I can also tell you it's very quiet.

### [Non water cooling option: ARCTIC - Alpine 11 Plus £9.8 (MSRP: £12)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ARCTIC-Alpine-11-PLUS-Sockets/dp/B00606OHQQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1532613241&sr=8-1&keywords=ARCTIC%2BAlpine%2B11%2BPlus&th=1)

[image: ARCTIC - Alpine 11]

**According to it's [page on PC Part Picker,](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/3jTmP6/arctic-cooling-cpu-cooler-ucacoap11301bua01) it has a noise profile of 14.0 db**, and it's [American Amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00606OHQQ), a maximum of 23 db, which puts it at about the same volume as "rustling leaves".

---

### [Thermal Paste Recommendation: Thermal Grizzly Kryonaut £7](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Thermal-Grizzly-Kryonaut-thermal-grease/dp/B011F7W3LU/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1532613933&sr=8-2&keywords=thermal%20grizzly%20kryonaut)

[image: Thermal Grizzly Kryonaut]

One of the best ceramic thermal pastes out there. Also happens to be the exact thermal paste I used with the Cooler Master upgrade on the LGA 1155 socket. As a reminder, you may want to buy some Isopropyl alcohol (nail polish remover) to help clean off the original thermal paste. Also remember you don't need to put a lot of thermal paste on the CPU to get it to work.